# Create FPDF by code and call it by method

Tags: php, fpdf

In my project I use `fpdf` to generate a PDF-file based on data from database.
However I would like to pregenerate the pdf by calling some method that create and save the file.
save_data.php

```
($myPDF->createPDF($id)){
 echo 'File was created';
}else{
 echo 'There was a problem creating the file';
}
```

createPDF.php

```
//Code that generate the PDF using FPDF and at end save the file to server
$pdf->Output('/var/www/html/my_dir/my_pdf.pdf','F');
```

So basically I would like to place createPDF.php in a method and then return `true` or `false` if pdf was created or not.

**EDIT:**
Just to clarify. If I could just get a response from `Output()` it would be much easier.

Should I proceed and just check if file exists or not?

Comment: Check it first and display a user-friendly (or something that's good to see) reminder/info.

Comment: It is unclear what you ask. Obviously you can call the code that creates the document from within some method, sure. Question is if it is such a good idea to use a file, though. The issue with files is generating unique names to prevent collisions and to clean the files up after some time. Why not use an output buffer instead which you can read instead of a file?

Comment: Thing is that I need the file to be on server for later use. If the file does not look good. The user may adjust the input and have the file replaced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to know if the file has been successfully saved to disc:

```
function createPdf($pdf, $filename) {
  // remove file if it already exists
  if(file_exists($filename)) unlink($filename);

  // save pdf
  $pdf->output($filename, 'F');

  // return true if successfull, false otherwise
  return file_exists($filename);
}
```

Comment: Thanks ideally I would like to place it as an method and then generate the PDF like:
`$pdf = $buildPDF->build($db_value);`
`if($buildPDF->createPdf($pdf, $filename)){ //File generated and I can email it as attachment etc }`